# $S$-differentiable functions.

Tags: real-analysis

I just thought of this fun exercise:

Let $S=\bigcup \{D\subseteq \Bbb R: \text{$D$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ and $|D|=\aleph_0$}\}$.

We say a function $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ is $S$-differentiable at $x$, and call this number $Sf'(x)$ if the limit $$\lim_{z\to x,\,z\in S}\frac {f(z)-f(x)}{z-x}$$

Exists. In that case, the limit is $Sf'(x)$.

**Question**

Are there $S$-differentiable functions which are not differentiable in the regular sense?

Comment: It looks like $S$ is all of $\mathbb R,$ so big fat no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S$ is $\Bbb R$. To prove this, examine the following equivalence relation: $a\sim  b $ iff $a-b\in\Bbb Q$.

This equivalence relation essentially partitions $\Bbb R$ into an uncountable number of "copies" of $\Bbb Q$; the cosets of $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb R$. Each of these is countable, and each of these is dense.

Another, easier way, is to for each irrational number $a$, let $\mathcal Ia$ represent $\Bbb Q\cup \{a\}$. Each of these is countable, because it's a countable set unioned with a countable set, and each of them is dense, because they have a dense subset.

Comment: Thanks! I could understand the second way, I don't really see how the first relation partitions $\Bbb R$ into the uncountable number of $\Bbb Q$'s. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Think about each equivalence class in this partition. For any equivalence class $[a]$, each $a+q$ for $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ is in $[a]$.